# Iam trying to modify the numbers in the bracket of the right most corner containing certain keyword using regex equation/python

Tags: python, regex

```
#define CANIF_AR_RELEASE_MAJOR_VERSION     (999U)
#define CANIF_AR_RELEASE_MINOR_VERSION     (2U)
#define CANIF_AR_RELEASE_REVISION_VERSION  (2U)
#define TEST_CANTRCV_MODULE_ID             (70U)  /* 0x46 */
```

here i want the output as

```
#define CANIF_AR_RELEASE_MAJOR_VERSION     (0)
#define CANIF_AR_RELEASE_MINOR_VERSION     (0)
#define CANIF_AR_RELEASE_REVISION_VERSION  (0)
#define TEST_CANTRCV_MODULE_ID             (70U)  /* 0x46 */
```

only to check for keyword VERSION and replace the value in bracket which may have alphabets , numbers inside the brackets
in future if possible i want to read these specific values from another file and replace them in the current file please help i will be forever grateful
currently iam using expression

```
import re
with open ('McalLib_Cfg.h', 'r' ) as f:
    content = f.read()
    content_new = re.sub('\([^\)][0-99\)[A-Z][\b)]([0-9]?)$', r'(0))', content, flags = re.M)
    content_new1=re.sub('[[^\)][0-9\[0-9)[A-Z][)]+',r')0)',content_new,flags = re.M)
    content_new2=re.sub('\([^\)][\b\]([1-9]|[1-9][0-9][a-zA-Z]',r'0',content_new1,flags = re.M.I)
    content_new3 = re.sub('\([^\)][0-99\)[A-Z][\b)]([0-9]?)([/)])$', r'(0)', content_new2, flags = re.M)

    

    
with open('McalLib_Cfg1.h', 'w') as file:
  file.write(content_new3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look for version until the parenthesis and capture that. Then match numbers or chars A-Z in between the parenthesis to replace.

Note that as you also have `/* 0x46 */` in the examples, if that is also valid after the parenthesis then using `$` to assert the end of the string would not work.

```
(VERSION[^\S\n]+\()[A-Z0-9]+(?=\))
```

The pattern matches:

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `VERSION[^\S\n]+\(` Match VERSION and 1+ whitespace chars without newlines
- `)` Close group 1
- `[A-Z0-9]+` Match 1+ chars A-Z or 0-9
- `(?=\))` Positive lookahead, assert `)` to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E5KTwB/1)

In the replacement use capture group 1 followed by a zero in this case:

```
\g<1>0

import re

with open('McalLib_Cfg.h', 'r') as f:
    content = re.sub(r'(VERSION[^\S\n]+\()[A-Z0-9]+(?=\))', r'\g<1>0', f.read())
    print(content)
```

Output

```
#define CANIF_AR_RELEASE_MAJOR_VERSION     (0)
#define CANIF_AR_RELEASE_MINOR_VERSION     (0)
#define CANIF_AR_RELEASE_REVISION_VERSION  (0)
#define TEST_CANTRCV_MODULE_ID             (70U)  /* 0x46 */
```

---

To match the strings from the start of the line with `#define`

```
^(#define[^\S\n]+\w+VERSION[^\S\n]+\()[A-Z0-9]+(?=\))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mW5OMi/1)